# Why does my Node.js/Mongodb program hang on insertOne()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a Node.js application that recursively reads a directory for MP3 and FLAC files and inserts their metadata and filepath as documents in a Mongodb collection. Here's the listing:

```
/**
 * File: import/import.js
 * Desc: A program that reads and imports media files into mongodb
 */

"use strict"

var assert = require("assert")
  , dir = require("node-dir")
  , fs = require("fs")
  , mm = require("musicmetadata")
  , mongodb = require("mongodb")
  , parseArgs = require("minimist")
  , path = require("path")

//////////
// Main //
//////////

var argv = parseArgs( process.argv.slice(2)
                    , { "boolean": [ "d", "debug" ] }
                    )

var debug = argv["d"] !== false || argv["debug"] !== false
if (debug) console.log("Debug enabled.")

var url = "mongodb://localhost"
  , db
  , coll
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, database) {
  if (err) throw err
  if (debug) console.log("Connected to mongodb.")
  db = database
  coll = db.collection("coolname")
  main()
})

function main() {
  var dirArg = argv._.length >= 1
             ? argv._[0]
             : process.cwd()
  dirArg = path.resolve(process.cwd(), dirArg)

  if (debug) {
    coll.insertOne( { "foo": "bar" }, function (err, r) {
      assert.equal(null, err)
      assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount)
      console.log(r)
    })
  }

  if (debug) {
    console.log("Beginning recursive descent from " + dirArg)
  }

  dir.files(dirArg, handleFiles)
}

///////////////
// Functions //
///////////////

/**
 * Iterates through `files` and adds each MP3 and FLAC file
 * to a mongodb database.
 */
function handleFiles(err, files) {
  if (err) throw err
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    fs.lstat(file, function (err, stats) {
      if (err) throw err
      if (!stats.isFile()) return
      var ext = path.extname(file)
      if (ext === ".mp3" || ext === ".flac") handleMedia(file)
    })
  })
}

/**
 * Adds `file` to a mongodb instance.
 */
function handleMedia(file) {
  var parser = mm(fs.createReadStream(file), function (err, metadata) {
    if (err) throw err
    metadata.filepath = file
    if (debug) console.log(metadata)
    coll.insertOne(metadata, function (err, r) {
      assert.equal(null, err)
      assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount)
      if (debug) console.log("In callback")
    })
  })
}
```

My program appears to connect to my Mongodb instance successfuly, and my logging shows that I should have several successful calls to `insertOne()`, but instead of finishing, my program ends up hanging in the callbacks passed to that function. In addition, since those callbacks have no error and the passed `WriteOpResult` object reports an `insertedCount` of 1 each time, I would expect to find some records inserted into my collection but querying the collection yields nothing each time.

I'm trying to apply the examples given in Mongodb's documentation, but I cannot determine what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what I was doing wrong. Records were getting inserted; I just didn't understand the mongo shell. In addition, the node process will stay open until something calls db.close(). Now I just need to figure out how I call that after all my callbacks are finished :/